# Rails project not running in Rubymine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymine

When I start my Rails project in Rubymine and run it with the green button, I get this error message:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) /Users/Josh/RubymineProjects/untitled/bin/rails server -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000 -e development
/Users/Josh/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:347:in `block in verify_gemfile_dependencies_are_found!': Could not find gem 'sass-rails (~> 5.0) ruby' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or available on this machine. (Bundler::GemNotFound)
  from /Users/Josh/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:325:in `each'
  from /Users/Josh/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:325:in `verify_gemfile_dependencies_are_found!'
  from /Users/Josh/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:198:in `start'
  from /Users/Josh/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:182:in `resolve'
  from /Users/Josh/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:200:in `resolve'
  from /Users/Josh/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:140:in `specs'
  from /Users/Josh/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:185:in `specs_for'
  from /Users/Josh/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:174:in `requested_specs'
  from /Users/Josh/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/environment.rb:18:in `requested_specs'
  from /Users/Josh/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in `setup'
  from /Users/Josh/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler.rb:127:in `setup'
  from /Users/Josh/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/setup.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
  from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in `require'
  from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in `rescue in require'
  from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in `require'
  from /Users/Josh/RubymineProjects/untitled/config/boot.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
  from /Users/Josh/RubymineProjects/untitled/bin/rails:3:in `require_relative'
  from /Users/Josh/RubymineProjects/untitled/bin/rails:3:in `<top (required)>'
  from -e:1:in `load'
  from -e:1:in `<main>'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Any idea why this is happening or how it should be fixed? I'm using Rails v4.2, and Ruby v2.0 on a Macbook Pro.

Comment: Logs have already told you:

    Could not find gem 'sass-rails (~> 5.0)

Install gems via command:

    bundle install

Comment: "[What can I do when getting “This question body does not meet our quality standards”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92075/153968)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to follow a few steps to run projects in RubyMine. Make sure you have:

1. All gem installed. From RubyMine you can install gems.
2. The correct Ruby version in the RubyMine project. You can change the Ruby version from "Settings > Ruby version".

Comment: how do you install a gem from rubymine? how do i update my ruby version? sorry im new to ruby :/

Comment: Please check this link: https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/help/installing-and-uninstalling-gems.html